# Extending 3rd party Dart Component

Tags: angular, dart

I'm trying to use a `bs-table` from `ng_bootstrap` to show some info about some users. I've been able to do that and it works, but i have a problem with the `null values`, as all cell data is resolved by reflection, the table displays `null`. I've been trying to find a way to replace this `nulls` by aan empty String by as the code is from a 3rd party lib i can't edit it.

I thought about extending the `BsTableComponent` class so i could override the method that resolves the cell data, but i haven't been able to diplay any info with it, and i'm not getting any error either.

This is the code i tried so far, but it doesn't show me the table and i have data to show.

```
@Component(
selector: 'bs-table-custom',
template: <ommited for brevity>
directives: const [BsColumnDirective])
class BsTableCustomComponent extends BsTableComponent {
    String getData(dynamic row, String fieldName) =>
      fieldName.split('.').fold(row, (prev, String curr) {
        var prevValue = prev is Map
          ? prev[curr]
          : serializable.reflect(prev).invokeGetter(curr);

        if(prevValue == null || (prevValue is List && prevValue.isEmpty)) {
          return "";
        }

        return prevValue;
      }).toString();
```

I'm not sure how to extend a 3rd party lib in Dart or if there's a simpler way to achieve what i need.

Any help would be appretiated.
Thank you

Comment: Extending components is currently not supported. You can try and it might work but AFAIK you need to repeat all metadata `@Input()`, `@Output()`, `@ViewChild()`, ... in the subclass, also all `implements OnXxx`.

Comment: so i'd have to copy the lib... i've searched for an adapter or something like it that i could apply to the output but i didn't find any. I've tried to copy the whole class and use it, but i still get no data. i'll probably have to copy the `BsTableComponent ` and the `BsColumnDirective` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by copying the files and editing them as needed.